# Compile Error IcePy (Ice 3.3.1) : relocation against local symbol

Tags: python, linker, compilation

I have a problem when I try to build IcePy (from Ice 3.3.1) (for python 2.4.4).
Compilation, testing and install of Ice itself (cpp version) is OK but when I tried to build the python interface ("py" directory) I get the following error (sorry for the truncated paths) :

```
.../lib/python2.4/config/libpython2.4.a(abstract.o):
relocation R_X86_64_32 against `a local symbol' can not be used when making
a shared object; recompile with -fPIC
.../lib/python2.4/config/libpython2.4.a: could not read symbols: Bad value
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
```

Is anybody able to explain me what this problem of *relocation* means (or at least give me a link) ? Thank you in avdance for your help. Even if you don't know anything about Ice, your comments on the error message are welcome.
(of course the compilation line already contained -fPIC so the "recompile with -fPIC" does not really help me...)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `abstract.o` was very likely *not* compiled with `-fPIC`, so the advice linker gave you is correct.

Go back to your build log, and verify that `-fPIC` is not there when `libpython2.4.a` was built. Note that `-fPIC` is needed for `libpython2.4.a` itself, not just for the IcePy.

If it *is* there, you have found a bug in GCC (which is somewhat unlikely).

You can learn about linkers and relocations [here](http://www.iecc.com/linker/linker07.html) or [here](http://www.airs.com/blog/archives/38).

Comment: Thank your for your answer. I think I will have definitely to recompile python (and it's not the first time but I wanted to avoid it). I will take a look at your links. That's exactly what I was looking for.